# Why cant this code draw a simple line on HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have this

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.lineWidth = .5 ;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#2068A8';
ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);

current = {'x':start.x,'y':start.y}
function draw(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    current.y+= 50;
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo( current.x, current.y  );
    ctx.moveTo( current.x, current.y  );
    ctx.stroke();
    if (current.y < finish.y) {
        setTimeout( draw, drawTime);
    }
}
setTimeout( draw, drawTime);
```

but there is no line drawn. What gives?

Comment: Everything starts at the start, but you don't seem to use your `to`.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it was the loop causing me problems but when you set ctx.beginPath() before everything else ESPECIALLY ctx.moveto it will work.  This is the changed answer

```
function drawLineSlowly(from, to){
var start = from || {'x':200,'y':0}, finish = {'x':225,'y':document.body.scrollHeight},
     drawTime = 2, current = 0;

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.lineWidth = .5 ;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#2068A8';
ctx.beginPath();


ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);



current = {'x':start.x,'y':start.y}

function draw(){


    current.y+= 50;
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo( current.x, current.y  );
    ctx.moveTo( current.x, current.y  );

    ctx.stroke();

    if (current.y < finish.y) {
    setTimeout( draw, drawTime);
    }

}

setTimeout( draw, drawTime);
```

}